# invoking superclass constructor

Tags: matlab, oop, constructor, superclass, matlab-class

I read [this documentation page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/calling-superclass-methods-on-subclass-objects.html) about how to invoke superclass constructor from a child class. The syntax they mention is this:

```
obj = obj@MySuperClass(SuperClassArguments);
```

I'm wondering what the purpose of `@` symbol in the above syntax is. Is the `@` symbol just a meaningless place occupier in the syntax *or* does the `@` symbol represent the [function handle symbol](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html) in MATLAB?

If I use:

```
obj = MySuperClass(SuperClassArguments);
```

instead of

```
obj = obj@MySuperClass(SuperClassArguments);
```

it still works fine. So what is the purpose of using `@` symbol?

Comment: I actually didn't realize you linked the function handle documentation. But the @ character certainly represents the function handle.

Comment: Yikes. Who makes up these syntaxes? Is there no one at The MathWorks whose job it is to maintain the consistency the language?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) no this has nothing to do with [function handles](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-handles.html), this is the syntax used to [call the superclass constructor](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/calling-superclass-methods-on-subclass-objects.html)

2) you could try it and see for yourself. Here is an example:

#### A.m

```
classdef A < handle
    properties
        a = 1
    end
    methods
        function obj = A()
            disp('A ctor')
        end
    end
end
```

#### B.m

```
classdef B < A
    properties
        b = 2
    end
    methods
        function obj = B()
            obj = obj@A();        %# correct way
            %#obj = A();          %# wrong way
            disp('B ctor')
        end
    end
end
```

With the correct syntax, we get:

```
>> b = B()
A ctor
B ctor
b = 
  B with properties:

    b: 2
    a: 1
```

If you use the commented line instead of the first one, you get the following error:

```
>> clear classes
>> b = B()
A ctor
A ctor
B ctor
When constructing an instance of class 'B', the constructor must preserve the class of the returned
object.
Error in B (line 8)
            disp('B ctor')
```